# Reuse startDestination Fragment on back stack with Android Navigation Component

Tags: android, kotlin, android-architecture-navigation

I am playing with Android Navigation Component in a little example app. So I have a Navigation Drawer as well as a Burger Button in my toolbar to open the drawer.

In the drawer there is an option to open a specific fragment (Say WebViewFragment). When setting up the appConfiguration in my MainActivity, I passed in a set of all the fragments that can be accessed via the DrawerLayout.

```
        appBarConfiguration =
            AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
                setOf(
                    R.id.newsFragment,
                    R.id.webViewFragment,
                    R.id.loginFragment
                )
            )
                .setDrawerLayout(drawer)
                .build()
```

If I would not do that, the Burger button would change to a back arrow to indicate a possible back navigation, when the user navigates to one of those fragments.

This is all working fine, but I have a problem when I want to reuse one of the "start" fragments that can be accessed via the drawer layout. When I want to navigate from my MainFragment to the WebViewFragment, e.g. via a certain button, I expect the drawer button to change to a back button. But since I passed the WebViewFragment to the AppConfiguration, this seems to not be possible, it seems to be set in stone as "root" or "start destination". Does anyone know an answer to this that does not include inheriting from the WebViewFragment. 
I want to avoid this since I'm not a fan of inheritance and I don't think this is the right way to deal with this problem.

I really appreciate any kind of advice.

Comment: If `webViewFragment` is accessible from the drawer layout, then it is a top-level fragment, and therefore won't show the UP arrow.

Comment: Thanks, I was hoping for a better solution, but will probably add DrawerWebViewFragment which inherits from WebViewFragment and does nothing else. Just so I can declare DrawerWebViewFragment as top-level fragment.